# Error installing rabbitmq helm as dependency

Tags: rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm

When I try to install my helm that is dependent from a rabbitmq chart, the rabbitmq pod gives me this error:

```
ls: cannot open directory '/bitnami/rabbitmq/mnesia': Permission denied
```

ERROR IMAGE: [error ls: cannot open directory '/bitnami/rabbitmq/mnesia': Permission denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iGh8.png)

My dependency configuration is as follows:

```
dependencies:
- name: rabbitmq
  version: "8.24.1"
  repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
  condition: broker.enabled
```

How I can use the rabbitmq helm as a dependency?

Comment: Did you already do `helm dep build`?

Comment: Yes I did, even tried to use others versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody needing this, I was using k3d for the local development and this permission conflict seens to be related to k3d, so I started to use minikube instead and now it's working.

Comment: At this point in time, it's not even really touching your cluster. I think you did more than just this and are misguided.

Comment: I just got out of alternatives, at what part of the structure you think this could be related?

Comment: did you set fsGroup? Or any other kind of security context? Looks to me like its not running as root user from your screen shot and is not allowed to write into a volume. So its touching your cluster. I havent seen the screenshot sorry.

Comment: you can try fsGroup: 2000

Comment: but you could also make the question more detailed. Its hard to understand that your container is throwing that error and not helm itself, without clicking the link. Its not even clear that the link points to an image.

Comment: Thanks, the error I could not get again but I edited to be more clear that is an image of the error

Comment: about setting the fsgroup, I wanted to use the helm from bitnami without having to download the helm folder from them, just referencing the dependency

Comment: usually a helm chart will allow you to set security context as value though.